# how to loop + 7 days and display the data based on that loop

Tags: php

I have a problem with my code, I want to show `Tadarus`, `Kajian`, `Edukasi` and `Umum`. example I have variable `$startdate = '2019-09-20'`.

If `$startdate + 7day`, I want to echo `Tadarus` 
If `$startdate + 14day`, I want to echo `Kajian` 
If `$startdate + 21day`, I want to echo `Edukasi`
If `$startdate + 28day`, I want to echo `Umum`

and then if last echo is `Umum`, I want to show data from `Tadarus` again. This is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
$getdate = date("Y-m-d");
if (strtotime("+7 day", $getdate)) {
   echo "Tadarus";
}elseif(strtotime("+14 day", $getdate)){
   echo "Kajian";
}elseif(strtotime("+21 day", $getdate)){
   echo "Edukasi";
}elseif(strtotime("+28 day", $getdate)){
 echo "Umum";
}
```

Comment: You aren't using `$startdate` in your code...

Comment: sorry I copied the variable wrong

Comment: Calling `strtotime()` will return a unix time stamp, so the first `if` will _always_ evaluate as `true`. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here? If you start by getting the current date, what exactly are you trying to compare against? Right now, you're just checking if you get a "truthy" value from `strtotime()`.

Comment: all I do is display data based on differences from date and current date +7 days, +14 days, +21 days and +28 days. and actually the current date will be saved to the database as the date of registration, and if the registration date is +7 days then the user must do a tadarus, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like that:

```
function echoBasedOnDay($date) {
    if ($date === date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days"))) {
        echo "Tadarus";
    } elseif($date === date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+14 days"))){
        echo "Kajian";
    } elseif($date === date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days"))){
        echo "Edukasi";
    } elseif($date === date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days"))){
        echo "Umum";
    }
}

echoBasedOnDay(date('2019-09-27')); // You can pass any date you want in here as the function's parameter
```